# Getting images from SD-CARD for a custom Dialog

Tags: android

### Getting images from SD-CARD for a custom Dialog

---

**What I am trying to do**:: *I am trying to learn to use `dialogs`, `OnClick` of `imageview` i want to display a custom dialog which has images stored in `sdcard`. then `on-select of any one image`, I want to `set` the image for `imageview`*

**What i have done**:: *I have achieved above specifications for images from drawable*

---

**DataAcceptActivity.java**

```
public class DataAcceptActivity extends Activity {

    InputStream is;

    EditText name;
    ImageView imageView;


    int[] image_array={R.drawable.index,R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.image5,R.drawable.image6,R.drawable.image7,R.drawable.image8,R.drawable.image9,R.drawable.image10};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new  OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                showImages();
            }
        });


    }



    protected void showImages() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final Dialog dlg=new Dialog(DataAcceptActivity.this);
        dlg.setContentView(R.layout.grid_view);
        GridView GV=(GridView) dlg.findViewById(R.id.gridView_id);
        GV.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(DataAcceptActivity.this));

        GV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                imageView.setImageResource(image_array[arg2]);
                dlg.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dlg.show();

    }


    class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        Context cxt;
        public ImageAdapter(DataAcceptActivity dataAcceptActivity) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.cxt=dataAcceptActivity;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return  image_array.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ImageView imageView ;
            if(convertView==null){
                imageView=new ImageView(cxt);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);
            }else{
                imageView=(ImageView) convertView;
            }

            imageView.setImageResource(image_array[position]);
            return imageView;
        }

    }

}
```

How can i modify code to achieve my goals !

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This are Arraylist that hold the bitmap that create from image path

```
 ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps= new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
```

> This is your Image folder path

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePath()+"/Stampii/");
```

> This is list of image in folder

```
file imageList[] = file.listFiles();

This code take image from path and store in bitmap arraylist.

 for(int i=0;i<imageList.length;i++)
 {
   Log.e("Image: "+i+": path", imageList[i].getAbsolutePath());

   Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageList[i].getAbsolutePath());

   bitmaps.add(b);

 }
```

Now, use this `Bitmap array` within  `int[] image_array` and use `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmaps.get(position));` for  `imageView.setImageResource(image_array[position]);`

Thanks

Comment: Thanks ! this helped .... i also refered .... http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/04/20/select-an-image-from-gallery-in-android-and-show-it-in-an-imageview/ ......... which is a great reference